# Css: responsive other divs when hide a previous div

Tags: css, responsive

My page here: https://webtan.jp/

I hide this section:

```
#top__fullcarousel {
    display: none;
```

}

but after hiding it, the following part (the **siteContent** block) didn't fit (
[the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dLmv.png))

I fixed the padding and it's only working with viewport(min width 1200px), not working rightly with other viewports (mobile, ipad...)

```
.siteContent {
    padding-top: 129px;
```

}

How can I responsive it in this case?

Comment: use media queries. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set padding that you need for each by each device width:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .siteContent {
    padding-top: 129px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .siteContent {
    padding-top: 109px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .siteContent {
    padding-top: 89px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .siteContent {
    padding-top: 69px;
  }
}
```

Of course you can use a lot of another methods, but this one is most ease way.